# Reacting to Android root command 'du'

Tags: android, root, du

I have an app that successfully gets root access and executes 2 simple commands; `cd /` and `du`. I'm not even sure if the `cd` is necessary because I think that's where you end up after you `su`. But anyways.. running `du` prints out a lot of info. What I want to do is `something()` whenever I discover a folder with a size of zero. Am I going to have to walk through and query every folder manually, or is there some way to "listen" to the `du` output and act on it? I'm pretty good at scripting, but I know little about running Linux commands from an application...

FYI I'm using a slightly modified version of [this](http://muzikant-android.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-get-root-access-and-execute.html) example to run my commands.

### Update

Here's what I have so far... `du` prints out something like

```
205244    ./data
0         ./dev
```

So if use `du | cut -c1 | grep '0'` I get a bunch of zeroes. This is good.. I think. But now that I've narrowed the list to entries with 0 in the 1st column, how would I use `grep` and `cut` to only print *the path* of 0-size directories?

Also, is `cut -c1` going to be reliable? Could there be a case where the dir wasn't 0-size but had a leading zero in the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to try this.
Be warned: it is recursive.

```
find ./ -type d -empty -exec ls -ld {} \;
```

please manually check the output is right before attempting to apply your something() :)

Comment: Hmm.. well like I said, I don't know much about linux commands so I don't know how to "pipe".. although I know what `grep` is. I'll do some research, but I may be back for more help. Thank you!

Comment: tacone, please read the update in the answer. It seems I still need help!

Comment: I did a quick test, and in my test even empty directories have no zero size.
The directory with 0 size you listed in your questions are special linux directories, they seem real dirs, in reality they are read only rappresentation of what is going on in the phone.

Comment: When I run this, it prints `unrecognized: -empty` Is this an Android issue?